# Pandas Identify Rows where two columns have same strings

Tags: python, pandas

The wording of the question might be confusing, but in the following data frame, I would like to be able to pick the first and last row:

```
dt = [['BOS','SF'],['SF','LA'],['LA','NYC'],['SF','BOS'],
      ]
my_df= pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Source','destination'], data = dt)
my_df
```

In other words, identify pairs of rows, where destination of the first row is the source of the other and vice versa.

Seems like an easy problem, but I am unable to come up with any solution.

Comment: hi, what if there is another row with `["BOS", "SF"]`, what should happen to it and the end result?

Comment: @MustafaAydın, I would drop that row with `.drop_duplicates()` method.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification; I'd written an answer and now undeleted it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to ignore the order between two columns is to sort each row within itself, which `np.sort` can do. Then you can form a new dataframe with these ordered rows. `duplicated` with `keep=False` will mark all the duplicated rows as `True` which we can use as a mask to index the original dataframe:

```
rows_sorted_df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df))
dups = rows_sorted_df.duplicated(keep=False)
result = df[dups]
```

to get

```
>>> rows_sorted_df

     0    1
0  BOS   SF
1   LA   SF
2   LA  NYC
3  BOS   SF

>>> dups

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True

>>> result

  Source destination
0    BOS          SF
3     SF         BOS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you separate your columns into individual dataframes, you can then merge them to get only the rows that match.

(In this example I renamed the column to 'code' in each df; alternatively you could specify the `right_on` and `left_on` arguments in the `merge` call.)

```
s = my_df['Source'].reset_index().rename(columns={'Source':'code', 'index':'source_index'})
d = my_df['destination'].reset_index().rename(columns={'destination':'code', 'index':'dest_index'})

sd = pd.merge(s, d)


In: sd
Out: 
   source_index code  dest_index
0             0  BOS           3
1             1   SF           0
2             3   SF           0
3             2   LA           1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, thinking with Joins.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    dt = [['BOS', 'SF'], ['SF', 'LA'], ['LA', 'NYC'], ['SF', 'BOS'],
          ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Source', 'destination'], data=dt)
    df
```

|  | Source | destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BOS | SF |
| 1 | SF | LA |
| 2 | LA | NYC |
| 3 | SF | BOS |

calculate the matches between destination -> source

```
    left = df.copy()
    right = df.copy().set_index("Source")
    
    dest_to_source = left.join(right, on=[left["destination"]], 
    lsuffix='_original', rsuffix="_matched", how="inner")
    # pandas joins do weird things to the column names, so renaming and reordering
    dest_to_source.columns = ["Source_matched","Source_original","destination_original","destination_matched"]
    dest_to_source = dest_to_source[["Source_original","destination_original","Source_matched","destination_matched"]]
    dest_to_source
```

and this is the result:

|  | Source_original | destination_original | Source_matched | destination_matched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BOS | SF | SF | BOS |
| 1 | SF | LA | LA | SF |
| 2 | LA | NYC | NYC | LA |
| 3 | SF | BOS | BOS | SF |

then you can do the same thing for the source -> destination (for the "vice-versa" part of the question)\

```
    right = df.copy().set_index("destination")
    source_to_dest = left.join(right, on=[left["Source"]], lsuffix='_original',rsuffix='_matched', how="inner")
    source_to_dest.columns = ["destination_matched","Source_original","destination_original","Source_matched"]
    source_to_dest = source_to_dest[["Source_matched","destination_matched","Source_original","destination_original"]]
    source_to_dest
```

|  | Source_matched | destination_matched | Source_original | destination_original |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SF | BOS | BOS | SF |
| 1 | BOS | SF | SF | LA |
| 3 | BOS | SF | SF | BOS |
| 2 | SF | LA | LA | NYC |

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best way to do this is by using `join` like so:

```
import pandas as pd

dt = [
  ['BOS','SF'],
  ['SF','LA'],
  ['LA','NYC'],
  ['SF','BOS'],
]

my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Source','destination'], data = dt)
source_df = my_df.set_index('Source')
dest_df = my_df.set_index('destination')
joined_df = source_df.join(dest_df)

print(joined_df)
```

This is the output (a bit confusing at first):

```
    destination Source
BOS          SF     SF
LA          NYC     SF
SF           LA    BOS
SF          BOS    BOS
```

If we think about it a bit deeper it makes sense. Let's take these rows from the input:

```
  ['SF','LA'],
  ['LA','NYC'],
```

Our join turns these rows into "source -> middle -> dest", or "SF -> LA -> NYC". Looking at our resulting table

```
    destination Source
LA          NYC     SF
```

We can read this as "From the Source column 'SF' to the destination column 'NYC' through the index of the row 'LA'. If you would like the dataframe to be more readable, you can can add the following:

```
joined_df.index.name = 'middle'
joined_df = joined_df.reset_index()
print(joined_df)
```